# Running MYSQL for database generation

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm attempting to run MYSQLD to generate some data for dump to file in docker image (I don't actually need to MYSQL running after that)

```
USER mysql
RUN mysqld --initialize-insecure 
RUN mysqld --daemonize --skip-networking    
RUN mysql --protocol=socket -uroot -hlocalhost -e "create table DDD"
```

All seems to go fine until I hit

```
"0.205 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)",
```

which is strange to me as I get it right after

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

what am I'm doing wrong?

```
#15 [11/13] RUN mysqld --initialize-insecure
#15 0.210 2020-05-03T21:27:14.416004Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) initializing of server in progress as process 7
#15 0.211 2020-05-03T21:27:14.420895Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
#15 0.535 2020-05-03T21:27:14.744127Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
#15 1.665 2020-05-03T21:27:15.874257Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
#15 DONE 3.7s

#16 [12/13] RUN mysqld --daemonize --skip-networking
#16 0.434 2020-05-03T21:27:18.296394Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010101] [Server] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Location is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
#16 0.434 2020-05-03T21:27:18.296447Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 8
#16 0.435 2020-05-03T21:27:18.309882Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
#16 2.820 2020-05-03T21:27:20.693463Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
#16 3.005 2020-05-03T21:27:20.878562Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock'
#16 3.214 2020-05-03T21:27:21.087873Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
#16 3.230 2020-05-03T21:27:21.103997Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
#16 DONE 3.9s

#17 [13/13] RUN mysql --protocol=socket -uroot -hlocalhost -e "create table ...
#17 0.205 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
#17 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mysql --protocol=socket -uroot -hlocalhost -e "create table DDD"]: runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RUN` *build* stages of a docker file are executed sequentially. You can't run a daemon process there available for the next step.

Use the docker library's [mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), and under the "Initializing a fresh instance" heading lists a number of SQL/script mechanisms in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` that will initialize a database for you.

You can immediately shutdown after this has been run (maybe even a script at the end of the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` that returns failure)